# Changing padding in woo-commerce messages

Tags: html, css

I am trying to change the padding between the button and messages on either side of the page when the user makes an action, for example adding a product to the cart.

Video of problem below

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TrXx-tpc1j4

Website: [zamiafashion.com/](http://www.zamiafashion.com/)

Comment: Could you please post the CSS in question? I can't see what you're looking at on a low res video :p

Comment: I cant it't like 100,000 character over the limit.

Comment: Cant I send you a word document of it??

Answer (score 0):

Without any code to go on, it looks like you can narrow down the following.

The left element/check mark is looks to be `.woocommerce-message`

```
 .woocommerce-message{color: #7a9c59!important}

 .woocommerce-message:before,.woocommerce-message
   :after{color: #FFF!important; background-color:#7a9c59!important }
```

There's like 50 css files linked to that page. I'm not going through 'em all. But what you should find is something that says

```
 .woocommerce-message:before { 
     content: someimagefile; }
```

Under that content: you can add your padding-left:

As for the View Cart button.. I think it `.button` or `.wc-forward` add `padding-right:` to that one

Just have to track that down :p
-- EDIT

Alright since the CSS files are plentiful and probably not the most user friendly to walk through, let's try a cheap work around with some inline styling. In your mark up find

```
 <div class="woocommerce-message"><a href="http://www.zamiafashion.com/cart/" class="button wc-forward">View Cart</a>
```

and try

```
<div class="woocommerce-message" style="padding-right: 20px;"><a href="http://www.zamiafashion.com/cart/" class="button wc-forward">View Cart</a
```

Comment: Do you know what file itd be in can you inspect element or something??

Comment: I found this.

 elseif (strpos($bg,'#') !== false) {
      $background_color = 'background-color:'.$bg.'!important';

Comment: That's a JS string I wouldn't play with. Edited my answer. Try an inline style work around if you can't find your CSS. It's on line 272